# Tensorflow 2: How can I use AdamOptimizer.minimize() for updating weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

In the first Tensorflow it was possible to just `minimize()`without any `var_list`. In Tensorflow 2 it is important to have a `var_list`included.
In my project I want to use the policy gradient algorithm to play TIC-TAC-TO.

How can I tune the weights of the model by calling minimizing. 
My idea was to do the following: `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(loss_func, var_list=self.model.weights)`

This my neural network:

```
class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self, learning_rate = 0.0001):    
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(243, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_dim=27)
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9)

        self.model.add(self.hidden_layer)
        self.model.add(self.output_layer)

        self.model.build()

    def training(self, board_state_memory, action_state_memory, G):
        loit = []
        for board_state in board_state_memory:
            loit.append(self.model.predict(x=board_state)[0])
        print(np.array(loit).shape)
        print(np.array(action_state_memory).shape)

        neg_log_prob = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=action_state_memory, logits=loit, name=None)
        loss_func = neg_log_prob * G
        print(loss_func)

        tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(loss_func, var_list=self.model.weights)

    def predict(self, board_state):
        output = self.model.predict(x=board_state)
        actions = tf.nn.softmax(output)
        return actions[0]
```

This did not work out and I got the error: `'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable`

How can I tune the weights of the model by the loss function. The easiest way.

This is my entire code:

```
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Basic implementation of the game:

```
class TicTacTo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.printing = False

    def setBoard(self):
        self.board = [0] * 9

    def getPlayerName(self, val):
        for player_name, player_value in PLAYER.items():
            if player_value == val:
                return player_name

    def printBoard(self):
        if (self.printing):
            boardDisplay = ['_'] * 9
            for i, val in enumerate(self.board):
                if val != 0:
                    boardDisplay[i] = self.getPlayerName(val)

            print(boardDisplay[0] + '|' + boardDisplay[1] + '|' + boardDisplay[2])
            print(boardDisplay[3] + '|' + boardDisplay[4] + '|' + boardDisplay[5])
            print(boardDisplay[6] + '|' + boardDisplay[7] + '|' + boardDisplay[8])

            print("\n")
    def printResult(self, result):
        if (self.printing):
            if result == 0:
                print("DRAW!")
            else:
                print("{} won the game!".format(self.getPlayerName(result)))

    @staticmethod
    def check(board):

        # check for diagonals
        if board[0] != 0 and board[0] == board[4] == board[8]: # check first diagonal
            return board[0]
        if board[2] != 0 and board[2] == board[4] == board[6]: # check second diagonal
            return board[2]

        # check horizontal
        for n in range(3):
            if (board[3*n+0] != 0) and (board[3*n+0] == board[3*n+1] == board[3*n+2]):
                return board[3*n+0]

        # check vertical
        for i in range(3): 
            if (board[i] != 0) and (board[i] == board[i+3] == board[i+6]):
                return board[i]

        # check for a draw
        if all(i != 0 for i in board): 
            return 0

        return 2

    def evaluate(self):
        result = TicTacTo.check(self.board)
        if result != 2: # check if game is finished
            self.printResult(result)
            return True
        return False

    """
    Player can take a move
    :param player: Object of the player
    :position: The position in the board where the move is set

    :return: Result of the game
        [1]  => Player X won
        [-1] => Player O won
        [0]  => Draw
        [2]  => Game is not finished
    """
    def move(self, player, position):
        self.board[position] = player.value
        self.printBoard()

        return self.evaluate()


    def availableMoves(self):
        empty = []
        for i, val in enumerate(self.board):
            if val == 0:
                empty.append(i)
        return empty


    def simulate(self, playerA, playerB):

        self.setBoard()
        self.printBoard()

        playerA.start()
        playerB.start()

        while True:

            moveA = playerA.turn(self.board, self.availableMoves())
            stop = self.move(playerA, moveA)
            if(stop): break

            moveB = playerB.turn(self.board, self.availableMoves())
            stop = self.move(playerB, moveB)
            if(stop): break

        result = TicTacTo.check(self.board)
        playerA.learn(result)
        playerB.learn(result)


    def simulations(self, playerA, playerB, games, printing):
        self.printing = printing
        x_win = 0
        o_win = 0
        draw = 0
        for n in range(games):
            self.simulate(playerA, playerB)
            result = TicTacTo.check(self.board)
            if (result == 0): draw += 1
            elif (result == 1): x_win += 1
            elif (result == -1): o_win += 1
        total = x_win + o_win + draw
        #print("Win X: {}%, Win O: {}%, Draw: {}%".format(100*(x_win/total), 100*(o_win/total), 100*(draw/total)))
        return x_win, o_win, draw
```

Evaluate the game:

```
def evaluu(game, playerA, playerB, num_battles, games_per_battle = 100):
    x_wins = []
    o_wins = []
    draws = []
    game_number = []
    game_counter = 0
    for i in range(num_battles):
        xwin, owin, draw = game.simulations(playerA, playerB, games_per_battle, False) 
        total = xwin + owin + draw
        print("End Win X: {}%, Win O: {}%, Draw: {}%".format(100*(xwin/total), 100*(owin/total), 100*(draw/total)))
        print("Round: ", game_counter)
        x_wins.append(xwin*100.0/games_per_battle)
        o_wins.append(owin*100.0/games_per_battle)
        draws.append(draw*100.0/games_per_battle)

        game_counter=game_counter+1
        game_number.append(game_counter)

    plt.ylabel('Game outcomes in %')
    plt.xlabel('Game number')

    plt.plot(game_number, draws, 'r-', label='Draw')
    plt.plot(game_number, x_wins, 'g-', label='Player X wins')
    plt.plot(game_number, o_wins, 'b-', label='Player O wins')
    plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=True, fancybox=True, framealpha =0.7)
```

Random--Player:

```
class RandomPlayer:
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.name = player_name
        self.value = PLAYER[self.name]

    def start(self):
        pass
    def turn(self, board, availableMoves):
        return availableMoves[random.randrange(0, len(availableMoves))]
    def learn(self, result):
        pass
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
```

NeuralNet:

```
class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self, learning_rate = 0.0001): 

        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(243, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_dim=27)
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9)

        self.model.add(self.hidden_layer)
        self.model.add(self.output_layer)

        #self.model.build()

    def training(self, board_state_memory, action_state_memory, G):
        loit = []
        for board_state in board_state_memory:
            loit.append(self.model.predict(x=board_state)[0])
        #print(np.array(loit).shape)
        #print(np.array(action_state_memory).shape)

        def loss(): 
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                neg_log_prob = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=loit, labels=action_state_memory, name=None)
                print(neg_log_prob * G)
                return neg_log_prob * G

        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=self.model.weights)

    def predict(self, board_state):
        output = self.model.predict(x=board_state)
        actions = tf.nn.softmax(output)
        return actions[0]
```

Policy Agent:

```
class PolicyAgent:
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.name = player_name
        self.value = PLAYER[self.name]

    def board_to_input(self, board):
        input_ = np.array([0] * 27)
        for i, val in enumerate(board):
            if val == self.value:
                input_[i] = 1  
            if val == self.value * -1:
                input_[i+9] = 1
            if val == 0:
                input_[i+18] = 1

        return np.reshape(input_, (1,-1))

    def start(self, learning_rate=0.001, gamma=0.1):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.moves = list(range(0,9))

        self.state_memory = []
        self.action_memory = []
        self.reward = [] #just one reward at end

        self.nn = NeuralNetwork(self.learning_rate)

    def turn(self, board, availableMoves):
        actions_prob = self.nn.predict(self.board_to_input(board))
        actions_prob = np.array(actions_prob)
        actions_prob /= actions_prob.sum()  # normalize

        #print(actions_prob)

        move = np.random.choice(self.moves, p=actions_prob)
        while move not in availableMoves:
            move = np.random.choice(self.moves, p=actions_prob)

        #print("Move: ", move)
        self.state_memory.append(self.board_to_input(board.copy()))
        self.action_memory.append(move)

        return move

    def calculateReward(self, end_reward):
        G = 0
        discount = 1

        runing = end_reward
        for t in range(len(self.action_memory)):
            G += runing
            runing = runing * discount 
            discount *= self.gamma

        return G

    def learn(self, result):
        if result == 0:
            reward = 0.5
        elif result == self.value:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = 0

        G = self.calculateReward(reward)
        print("G value: ", G)
        self.nn.training(self.state_memory, self.action_memory, G)

        self.state_memory = []
        self.action_memory = []
        self.reward = [] #just one reward at end
```

Try to simulate the game:

```
PLAYER = {"X": 1, "O": -1}
player20 = PolicyAgent("X")

u = TicTacTo()
u.simulations(player20, RandomPlayer("O"), 1, True)
```

Current Error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].
```

Comment: I believe it is in your loss_func, but without full code, I can't tell.

Comment: Should I send you my code?

Comment: Edit your post with your code would be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Initially:

```
self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
```

Try to have a loss parameter of the minimize method as python callable in TF2.

```
def loss(): 
    neg_log_prob = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=action_state_memory, logits=loit, name=None)
    return neg_log_prob * G 
    #return tf.square(predicted_y - desired_y)
```

Or:

```
def loss():
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(predicted_y - desired_y))
```

Do not convert lose to tensor:

```
self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.model.weights)
```

Call below codes after optimizer:

```
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess.run(init)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214300/discussion-on-answer-by-mahsa-hassankashi-tensorflow-2-how-can-i-use-adamoptimi).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd anaconda3
export PATH="$PATH:/home/username/anaconda3/bin"
source ~/.bashrc
anaconda-navigator
conda install tensorflow
```

I used nested with for runing session:
I got correct answer without exception:

***X won the game!
G value:  2.101***

```
def loss(): 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        with tensorflow.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            neg_log_prob = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=loit, labels=action_state_memory, name=None))


            sess.run(neg_log_prob)
            print(neg_log_prob * G)
            return neg_log_prob * G

    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=self.model.weights)
```

[image]

[TF1 vs TF2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Why do you use session. Is there a other possibility to solve that instead using Tensorflow 1 sessions?

Comment: The code did not tune the weight. I have print them out. I think that the self.optimizer do not have to be in the loss func. When I put that out of the loss func I get: ```ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor:```