# How to use Adam().minimize in tensorflow 2x?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, minimize

First I disable eager execution
Then, I compute my loss function as follows:

```
def loss_fn(x, y):
    y_ = model(x, training=True)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y))
    return loss
```

My optimizer is:

```
opt = Adam(1e-3)
```

Now, I want to minimize the above loss. I wrote the following code:

```
def train(x, y):
    loss = loss_fn(x, y)
    opt.minimize(loss, var_list=model.trainable_variables)
```

but I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I decided to try the following:

```
def train(x, y):
    loss = loss_fn(x, y)
    opt.minimize(lambda: loss, var_list=model.trainable_variables)
```

But I have also the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', ...]
```

I looked for some link but I didn't get what I want. Example of link: [Tensorflow 2: How can I use AdamOptimizer.minimize() for updating weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916156/tensorflow-2-how-can-i-use-adamoptimizer-minimize-for-updating-weights)

Someone to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minimize` function expects a loss function as a parameter in order to compute gradients using a gradient tape within it. So you may write `train` function this way,

```py
def train(x, y):
    opt.minimize(lambda : loss_fn(x, y), var_list=model.trainable_variables)
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. It works very well.